# How to Include events (not event-plugin) in Ractive initialization/defaults?

Tags: events, event-handling, ractivejs

I've read through the Ractive Documentation and I'm scratching my head a bit, because it seems like the default events initialization option allows me to do something - create new event*types* - far more complex than what i need  but conversely, there's no hook for the simpler, (more common?) task of defining default *events*

Could someone advise on how to provide global events that could be fired for traditional DOM events?

Example:

I have a 3 Component application page. I want to define a getOptions event, such that any `<select on-click='getOptions'>...</select>` will be handled by the same function. I don't want to have to define that function in each component.

My intuition would have been to do the following:

```
Ractive.events['getOptions'] = function(event){
   //logic for getting the options for the value in event.keypath
}
```

or, if i wanted a true default that could be overridden...

```
Ractive.default.events['getOptions'] = function(event){
   //logic for getting the options for the value in event.keypath
}
```

**but** my understanding of the documentation, is that `Ractive.events` and `Ractive.default.events` do *not* provide this, but rather provide a way to define new event plugins, that depend on a separate mechanism for getting fired:

```
Ractive.events.getoptions = function(node,fire){
   //here goes logic for interacting with DOM event listeners, etc
}
//and then i would need to do this
ractive = Ractive.extend({...});
ractive.on('someOtherEventName',function(event){
   //logic for getting the options for the value in event.keypath
});

//and then I could do this...
<select on-getoptions='someOtherEventName'>...</select>
```

**but what would *fire* the `getoptions` in this case - from the template, rather than js ractive.fire()?**

Would something like `<select on-getoptions='someOtherFunction' on-click=getoptions>...</select>` work? That seems very strange to me. Do I understand the concept correction? If not, what am i missing?

Is there a simple way to achieve the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ractive.events` refers to custom events for mediating between the dom and the template:

```
Ractive.events.banana = function( node, fire ) { ... };

<div on-banana="doSomething()"/>
```

The *handler* for the event can either be the name of an event to fire, or a method on the component instance.

In your case, I think defining a method on the `Ractive.prototype` would be the best way to have a common handler:

```
Ractive.prototype.getOptions = function( /* pass in arguments */ ){
    // and/or this.event will give you access 
    // to current event and thus context

    // you can also override this method in components and 
    // call this base method using this._super(..)
}

// now any ractive instance can use:
<select on-click="getOptions(data)">...</select>
```

An event based approach usually entails letting the root instance or common parent in the view hierarchy handle same event across child components:

```
var app = new Ractive({
    template: "<componentA/><componentB/>",
    oninit(){

        this.on( '*.getOptions', ( event, arg ) => {
            // any child component (at any depth)
            // that fires a "getOptions" event will
            // end up here
        });
    }
});

// in component A or B:
<select on-click="getOptions">...</select>
```

**UPDATE**: If you wanted to assign an event handler to the prototype, so in essence every component is pre-wired to handle an event of a set name, you could do:

```
Ractive.prototype.oninit = function(){
    this.on( 'getOptions', ( event ) => {
        // handle any "getOptions" event that happens in the instance
    });
}
```

Just be aware that you **must** call `this._super();` in any component in which you also implement `oninit`:

```
var Component = Ractive.extend({
    oninit() {
        // make sure we call the base or event listener won't happen!
        this._super();

        // do this component instances init work...
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @martypdx for above and speedy response!
I hadn't thought about using the prototype, but that makes a lot of sense and will work, i think, for the most part.

the event-bubbling feature you mention among components was something i was hoping to leverage, though.  is there any way to assign that to the prototype as well as a true event handler?

Comment: @LindsayRyan: added example of using prototype to register event listener

Comment: Awesome - thanks alot! 

In the meantime, I have found that i'm am not alone in wondering about this: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2514 (helpful maybe for others, too), but still wasn't sure...now i can get back to coding :)